# Templates inheritance with Freemarker

Tags: java, thymeleaf, freemarker, templating

I'm starting a new progect usign Freemarker as server-side template engine.

I often use Thymeleaf in my web project, adding Layout Dialect to create a hierarchy of template: starting from a main layout and *decorating* it with specific section for every page needed in my project.

I haven't used Freemarker very often, but, if I'm not wrong, it only implements templating by `include`/`import`.

Is there a way to use something like Thymeleaf Layout Dialect also with Freemarker?

In an old project I used Apache Tiles to do something similar, but now the project is retired. Is there any recent alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "inheritance" like in some other template engines. The main way of reusing pieces is with `#macro` (and `#nested`) in FreeMarker. Also note that macros are first class values, so they can be passed to other macros as arguments.